# MSSQL Query Help? Should be easy, but I must need more coffee?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I know this should be easy, but I can't see the forest for the trees.

```
TABLE 1
GNUM
Team1
Team2

TABLE 2
GNUM
ID
TeamID
```

For every record in table 1 there can be multiple related records in Table 2

Here's what I cant seem to figure out

I need to have a query that will tell me when there no records in TABLE2 for a specific team for a  specific game

```
For Example

TABLE1  
GNUM        Team1       Team2
1           A           B
2           A           C
3           B           A   
4           C           B   
5           B           A

TABLE 2
GNUM    TeamID
1       A
1       B
3       B
4       B
4       B
4       B
```

Given the Above I would need a query that would show me all the games with missing records in Table 2. For Example:

```
GNUM    Missing Team
2       A
2       C
3       A
4       C
5       B
5       A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` and `LEFT JOIN` for this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT GNUM, Team1
      FROM TABLE1  
      UNION
      SELECT GNUM, Team2
      FROM TABLE1  
      )a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b 
  ON a.GNUM = b.GNUM
  AND a.Team1 = b.TeamID
WHERE b.TeamID IS NULL
```

Comment: Man, I was so close.  Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GNUM, TEAM
FROM (
  SELECT t1.GNUM, Team1 AS TEAM
  FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.GNUM = t2.GNUM 
    AND t1.Team1 = t2.TeamID
  WHERE t2.TeamID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.GNUM, Team2 AS TEAM
  FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.GNUM = t2.GNUM 
    AND t1.Team2 = t2.TeamID
  WHERE t2.TeamID IS NULL
) t
ORDER BY GNUM, TEAM
```

Grab all the missing team 1 and team 2 rows separately, then combine the results.

Union all will be faster than union, as it doesn't perform a distinct operation. This is also desirable as in the unlikely event that a table1 contains (9, 'Z', 'Z') and table2 has no entries for game number 9, you would expect to see two rows of (9, 'Z') in the results.

If you don't care about record ordering, you can remove the wrapper query around the union to slightly increase performance.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c5da/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (select gnum, team1 t
      from table1
      union all
      select gnum, team2 t
      from table1) sq
where not exists(select top 1 1
                 from table2
                 where table2.gnum=sq.gnum and table2.teamid=sq.t)
```

You can see it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a839/4/0

Comment: Why the use of TOP 1 in an EXISTS clause? How could that possibly add any benefit?

Comment: Reflex to show the optimizer that I only care about a single row at maximum, and none of the columns themselves, since all I really want is whether the `select` returns anything or not.

Comment: If you're curious to see how much more expensive your query is, you can check the execution plan directly on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this approach :

```
SELECT GNUM, Team
  FROM (
       SELECT GNUM, Team1 AS Team
         FROM TABLE1  
       UNION
       SELECT GNUM, Team2 AS Team
         FROM TABLE1 ) AS TEAMS
 WHERE cast(GNUM as varchar(1)) + Team
       NOT IN (SELECT cast(GNUM as varchar(1)) + TeamID 
                 FROM TABLE2)
```

SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd931/7/0